# How to find out which is the parent (previous) uiviewcontroller? iphone

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, parent

For example I have 3 `UIViewController`s A, B, C.

I go trough `UIViewController`s like this:

```
 A -> B -> C -> B -> A
```

When we arrive in the `UIViewController` B, I want to know if I arrived in B from A or from C.

So I want to know which is the previous `UIViewController` of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

above other answer, you can maintain a tag for the view controller you're coming from, make a property of int tagViewControllerFrom, and set it when you push to B, from A or C, for A set something 1, or for C set something 2, both should be distinguished, then in viewDidLoad of B you can check it using if condition and do accodingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one :**

```
// In B

UIViewController* parentViewController = 
    (UIViewController*) [[self.view superview] nextResponder];

if ([parentViewController isEqualTo:viewControllerA])
{
}
else if ([parentViewController isEqualTo:viewControllerB])
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain a `weak` reference in your controllers (may be of `id` type) and can assign the parent controller to it when presenting the new controller